# "Normalizing" a matrix such that the matrix product with its transpose equals a diagonal matrix with specified values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

In his influential paper on "weak" factor models, [Onatski (2012)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407612000449) sets up a Monte Carlo simulation where the factor matrix $F$ fulfills $\frac{1}{T}F'F=I$ and the loadings matrix $\Lambda$ is chosen such that $\Lambda ' \Lambda$ equals a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements set to certain values (e.g. $d_1 = 30$, $d_2 = 20$, etc.). Now on page 253 of the paper, he describes how $F$ and $\Lambda$ are generated with standard i.i.d. Gaussian entries and then afterward "normalized" (whatever that means here) such that the 2 matrices fulfill the above-described assumptions.

With no prior knowledge on statistics and the characteristics of these 2 matrices, is there even a way to "normalize" $\Lambda$ in such a way? For matrix $F$, I would apply Gram-Schmidt to orthogonalize the matrix which should do the thing but I am clueless about $\Lambda$.

Comment: Your $F$ is a special case of $\Lambda$ for which all diagonal elements of $\Lambda'\Lambda$ are equal to $T$. So, it suffices to consider the generation of $\Lambda$ only. If the entries of $\Lambda$ are i.i.d. standard normal, then the expected value of the dot product between any two columns of $\Lambda$ are zero, meaning that the columns of $\Lambda$ are almost orthogonal to each other. Now one may use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation to turn those columns into mutually orthogonal ones. Then scale each column $i$ to make its norm equal to $\sqrt{d_i}$. Now you are done.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the silly question though, I really could have come up with that myself